# How to integrate manually copied hbase files into an hbase instance?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have copied the files associated an hbase table into another cluster and stored the files in the hbase folder.  I can see the table when i do a `list`. When I do `scan 'myTable'` it can't find the table.

When I go through the HBase-WebUI, I see the table including its cf information, when I click on the table I get:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: hbTable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:846)
```

How do i get the hbaseRegionServers to manage the table?

P.S. For the purposes of this exercise I'm not interested in using the export utility or the copyTable Utility.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link : [Complete Bulk Load](https://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#completebulkload)

Assuming here that you copied the Hfiles from one cluster to another.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the table in the other cluster? I think the error is due to the missing information in the .META

Comment: This approached worked, I created a table then copied the content of the cf table over - this was a small table not sure if the same approach would work for larger tables with multiple regions

Comment: while you copied the owner of the folder might have been changed, pls check if the owner is `hbase:hbase`

Comment: From @user3488171 (Tag him in your reply): So if i just create empty table in another cluster and then copy the Hfiles from the first cluster. Should it work fine?